# Why is gettimeofday() and time_t not making sense?

Tags: linux, time, openwrt

Why if I do the following:

```
struct timeval time;

gettimeofday(&time, NULL);

log("time seconds %i useconds %i", sizeof(time.tv_seconds), sizeof(time.tv_usec));
```

Does it return in openwrt:

```
time seconds 4 useconds 4259840
```

Is `time.tv_usec` using 4259840 bytes?  `tv_seconds` (since epoch) makes sense since it is a long long int. But `tv_usec` should always be below 1 million.

Answer (score 3):

The `sizeof` operator gives you back a `size_t` object.  You should be using the `%zu` format to print it out, not `%i`.  It's quite possible you're having some argument passing mishap as a result of the mismatched format strings and argument types.  If you crank up the warning level on your compiler, you should get a warning about it.  For example, clang tells me:

```
example.c:7:25: error: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long' [-Werror,-Wformat]
  printf("time seconds %i useconds %i\n", sizeof(time.tv_sec), ...
                       ~^                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       %lu
```

Of course, that may depend on how your `log()` function is implemented - which also might be the source of your bug.

Comment: They are both supposed to be long, but for some reason when I output them into a string in format of %li it doesn't work. So I have experimented and lli works for tv_seconds. tv_useconds always comes out wrong. Which is why I am trying to get a grip on what actual size these variables are.

Comment: @Nathan No: `struct timeval.tv_sec` is defined as a `time_t`, not a `long`. Furthermore, my manual tells me `struct timeval.tv_usec` is a `suseconds_t`, not a `long long`.

Answer (score 2):

Peering into my crystal ball...the problem is that your log function is incorrectly parsing its arguments.  Try printf instead.

Comment: What happens if you do: log("time seconds %i useconds %i", 4lu, 4lu )?

Comment: Holy crap, you are correct. I have no idea why it doesn't work though. More bugs, more bugs to do with strings!